# Oracle's (Java) RMI protocol in python?

Tags: python, java, rmi

Any implementation of Oracle's RMI protocol in python, .net or other non-Java language on GitHub? So far the one I found teaches you how to implement an RMI protocol from scratch. What I want is to implement Oracle's/Java's RMI protocol in Python or .NET

The specs here :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/rmi/protocol.html

Shouldn't be difficult as the protocol begins with `RMI://` Either the stub or skeleton can be done in Python.

Comment: Not possible in general. RMI runs over Java Object Serialization, so in general you will need a Java JVM with access to all referenced classes in the same serialization-version as used by the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62785523/11384184), it seems that java RMI is not designed to be implemented in other languages.

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763938/11384184) indicates that it is easier with JVM-based languages though. But not Python, because you would have to re-implement the entire RMI protocol. Would [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) be possible to use as implementation, instead of the popular (implicit) [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) ?

Otherwise, quoting [Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318758/joni) from its answer cited earlier :

> It will be easier to add a REST API to the Java service, which you can then call from .Net or from the Electron app.

The same goes for Python : just call a REST service in Java-land, instead of implementing the full RMI protocol.

Comment: CORBA and RMI are dead protocols.  Simple and open won.  HTTP and REST are the way to go.

Comment: @duffymo right, but sometimes you have a legacy behemoth that is still using RMI, and you may have to do it anyway. Though it would be quite the undertaking.

Comment: Jython's been dead for decades. Not a good idea to use it for any new development.

Comment: Your legacy behemoth is the real problem.  What plans are you making to modernize it?  You're only making it worse with your proposed solution.  Write an interface-based REST service in Java that uses RMI underneath.   Better than writing RMI from scratch.

Comment: @duffymo I'm not the OP, but I can imagine one case where it would be helpful : you already have the functionality implemented with Java RMI, and you need to call it from Python. But as suggested, adding a second entrypoint is probably simpler than to deal with RMI.

Comment: Agreed - wrap it in REST and call that from Python.